# React - Class component doesn't receive any params

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple class Component:

```
class SearchedUserWrapper extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            searchedPhrase: "",
            pageNumber: 1
        };
        this.increment = this.increment.bind(this);
    }

    GetUserForSearchResult = (postAmount, pageNumber) => {
        const list = [];
        for (let index = 0; index < postAmount; index++) {
            list.push(<SearchResultUser CurrentPage={pageNumber}></SearchResultUser>);
        }
        return list;
    }

    increment = () => {
        this.setState({ pageNumber: this.state.pageNumber + 1 })
        console.log(this.state.pageNumber + 0);
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
            {this.GetUserForSearchResult(5, this.props.pageNumber)}
            <Button onClick={this.increment}> Current page {this.state.pageNumber}</Button>
        </div>);
    }
}
```

and function `GetUserForSearchResult` receives a state from `SearchUserWrapper` class. My `SearchResultUser` looks like this:

```
class SearchResultUser extends Component {

    render() {
        {console.log(this.props.CurrentPage)}
        return (
            <div className="user-searchresult">
                {this.props.CurrentPage}
            </div>);
    }
}

export default SearchResultUser;
```

And console log says that this props are undefined, and the div is empty.

My goal is to have the effect that everytime I click "Current page" button, to refresh all the `SearchResultUser` component so that it displays a state passed as parameter. What am I doing here wrong? Why does it says to be undefined?

EDIT:
I tried couple of things and discovered something.

If I send the state in the params directly, for example:

```
    render() {
        return (<div>
            <SearchResultUser CurrentPage={this.state.pageNumber}></SearchResultUser>
        </div>
```

It seems to work, but the order of sending the state to the function, which passes it to params of component doesn't work.

```
  GetUserForSearchResult = (postAmount, pageNumber) => {
        const list = [];
        for (let index = 0; index < postAmount; index++) {
            list.push(<SearchResultUser CurrentPage={pageNumber}></SearchResultUser>);
        }
        return list;
    }

    render() {
        return (<div>
            <SearchResultUser CurrentPage={this.state.pageNumber}></SearchResultUser>
        </div>);
```

Can somebody explain why is it happening like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

In this place(below) I think you have to pass `state` instead of `props`, because the main component(`SearchedUserWrapper`) doesn't receive any `props`, so this is `undefined`.

```
{this.GetUserForSearchResult(5, this.props.pageNumber)}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-71594634-omvqpw

---

First message:

Did you check if the page number was updated?
If the next state depends on the current state, the doc of react recommend using the updater function form, instead:

```
this.setState((state) => {
  return {quantity: state.quantity + 1};
});
```

You should call super(props) before any other statement. Otherwise, this.props will be undefined in the constructor at `SearchResultUser`

---

Comment: Yes. In render method of `SearchedUserWrapper` the pageNumber state is being updated. I am sending this state as a parameter to another component via function and it doesn't work, no idea why. If I send the state directly into component like this: 
`<SearchResultUser CurrentPage={this.state.pageNumber}></SearchResultUser>` it works, but I dont know why.

Comment: In this place(`below`) I think you have to pass state instead of props, because the main component(`SearchedUserWrapper`) doesn't receive any props, so this is undefined.

`{this.GetUserForSearchResult(5, this.props.pageNumber)}`

Comment: You're right! I mistaken props for state, that's why it was undefined. Now it works. Do you mind editing your answetr to this so I can mark it as correct one?

Comment: Yes bro! Fist bump!